# Javascript: Global Variable Behaviour in IE8

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using Require.js for my current project.

And I used to load Require.js config with require variable like

```
require = {
  paths: {
    backbone: "libs/backbone-min",
    bootstrap: "libs/bootstrap.min",
    jquery: "libs/jquery-1.7.2.min",
    underscore: "libs/underscore-min",
    order: "plugins/order",
    text: "plugins/text",
    use: "plugins/use"
  }
};
<script src="http://local.gungroo.com/app/js/config.js"></script>
```

This worked fine in All browser.

Recently, I switched to Coffescript and the code generated is something like

```
(function() {
  window.require = {
    paths: {
      backbone: "libs/backbone-min",
      bootstrap: "libs/bootstrap.min",
      jquery: "libs/jquery-1.7.2.min",
      underscore: "libs/underscore-min",
      order: "plugins/order",
      text: "plugins/text",
      use: "plugins/use"
    }
  };

}).call(this);
```

But second one breaks in IE8.

Does IE8 treat variable 'var require' and 'window.require' differently?

Comment: Breaks as in, doesn't do what you want or errors out? If error, please specify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the requirejs documention about [configuration options](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config):

> Note: It is best to use var require = {} and do not use window.require
>   = {}, it will not behave correctly in IE.

This issue was reported to the requirejs project on github [here](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/125).  The issue reporter (dtanabe) offered some sample html and script that illustrates the problem.  I've created a fiddle available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eric_brenden/H22cr/) containing that sample code.  Notice that for IE 9 it works the same way as other browsers (e.g. Chrome, Firefox), but when I changed the document mode in the developer tools to IE 8 the problem showed up.  In response to this issue, jrburke (James Burke) added the documention that I mentioned above.

Comment: I figured that out in a hardway. Any idea what is the reason; the way IE handles them differently. Curious, even though IE's case is like a 'story'. Don't ask questions; it is, as it is. :)

Comment: @Saneef - I added more information to the answer including a link to the original issue report on github and a fiddle illustrating the issue.

Comment: This link http://tobyho.com/2013/03/13/window-prop-vs-global-var/ has a fairly good description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In a web browser:

```
window.require = 'herp';
// is equivalent to
require = 'derp';
```

`window` being the top level.

Comment: This is not necessarily the case in IE.